# What does the 3-sphere look like?

Tags: geometry

The 3-sphere is a surface of a 4D sphere, and is thus 3 dimensional. Then we should be able to look at it in our 3 dimensions. So what does it look like? Is it just a solid, 'filled-in' 3 dimensional sphere? If so, why doesn't Wikipedia just say that, instead of their convoluted explanation/photo 'stack of 3d spheres'? No mathematical jargon please.

Comment: no, it's not a 3-dimensional ball, but you can get the 3-sphere from the 3-ball ball by gluing every point on the surface together to a single point.

Comment: @Tim kinsella. What???

Comment: No, it's not a normal (3 dimensional) sphere, that's a 2-sphere (as stated on the Wiipedia page).

Comment: An interesting representation is brought by the Hopf fibration as described by an an answer of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3035513)

Comment: JamesA I think youre either wrong or unclear, as a 2-sphere is the surface of a 3D sphere and is not the entire 3D sphere. I suppose this answers my question though, in that a 2-sphere, though 2 dimensional, is represented in 3D. So the same should hold for a 3-sphere, in 4 dimensions.

Comment: A 2-sphere (normal sphere) is the boundry of a 3D *ball* (normal ball) (just as a 3-sphere is the boundry of a 4D *ball*); the word *sphere* already refers to just the surface (see [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere) if I was unclear). A 3D ball is a "filled in" (as you said in your question) 3D sphere.

Comment: Thank you, you just cleared up another question I had, which is 'what does B3 mean?' when using notation like R3 (real 3-space) or S3 (the 3-sphere, ie the unit shell of a 4 dimensional filled-in/solid sphere) and so on. Ie the n-sphere is defined as the shell of a n+1 dimensional solid sphere. The answer is that B3 means the ball of 3 dimensions (filled in, solid, etc.). And Bn means the same of n dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 3-sphere cannot fit into 3-dimensional euclidean space, just as a 2-sphere cannot be cut from a piece of paper. So while you can't just "look at it", here are two nice visualizations of what it would look like *being inside* the 3-sphere:

[Spherical Geometry Is Stranger Than Hyperbolic - Hyperbolica Devlog #2](https://youtu.be/yY9GAyJtuJ0)

[Spherical Space Building Game (Non-Euclidean Minecraft)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=MtrgYVnKpGE)

Interactive visualizations of 3-spheres, among other things, are available in your browser ([3-dimensional.space](http://www.3-dimensional.space/)) or downloadable ([Curved Spaces](https://www.geometrygames.org/CurvedSpaces/index.html.en)).