# On the existence of Villarceau circles

Tags: geometry

I thought about a sketch proof of the existence of the Villarceau circles, and I would like to know if there are some evident flaw:
I consider a pool table with no friction, no holes, and following the laws of reflection. I can deform the pool table glueing the border and transforming it into a torus, so I can map the trajectories of the point-like ball on the pool table into the ones on the torus.
If I hit the ball positioned in the point P, I unfold the pool table and draw another one on the edge where the balls hit first and so on, so the ball's trajectory is a straight line.
The 4 circles on the torus will be the trajectories that will come back in P with the less rebounds.
I attach a pic to show the unfolding of the pool table.
Is it possible to prove the existence of those circles in this way?[image]

Comment: Briefly yes, that looks like a good explanation. In more detail, I'd personally be inclined not to think of billiards (with reflection), but to lift to the universal covering of the torus (two unfoldings) and see there are line segments "wrapping once around each direction. Depending on your definitions, there may be the separate issue of showing these curves project to Euclidean circles under stereographic projection from the $3$-sphere to Euclidean three-space.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me if, talking about universal covering, is possible to calculate the slope of the plane creating the Villarceau circles (Tan[φ]=r/Sqrt[R^2-r^2] )?

Comment: I haven't checked details, but "it should be," though the natural approach wouldn't be intrinsic to the aspect ratio of the rectangle, but would entail looking at Hopf tori (with the given aspect ratio) in the three-sphere, stereographically projecting them to Euclidean space, and calculating the plane using three-dimensional geometry. (If the question is how to pass from the aspect ratio of the rectangle to the minor and major radii r and R, yes, that's straightforward.)

Comment: The Villarceau circles appear in a natural way through Hopf torii mentionned by @Andrew D. Hwang : they can be obtained using the Hopf fibration and stereographic projection as explained in an answer of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3035513).