# What is the 3-dimensional equivalent of this 1-dimensional problem?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Consider a thin cylinder. On this cylinder a circle can move. From a distance this looks as if a point-particle moves on a line. This is somewhat reminiscent to Kaluza-Klein, except that KK brings a true classical point particle in.
We can describe this situation as one dimension of a 2D space curled up to a circle.

How can we mathematically describe a 6D space of which three dimensions are curled up to a circle? Do we need a 6x6 metric matrix of space (like a 5x5 metric matrix in KK theory (where time is involved)

Maybe I'm not clear enough, so let me write some more. In the case of the cylinder you can place tiny (Planck-sized) circles on it which move in one dimension.
Can we do the same for a 6D space? I mean, curl three of the large dimension up to tiny circles so we get a structure that looks like 3D space (like the thin cylinder looks like 1D), and on which we can place  3D structures (spheres?) that can move in all three dimensions (like the 1D circle can move in one, in the cylinder case)?

I hope I made myself clear a bit. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's rather difficult for me (maybe for others too) to figure out what you are referring too. The only thing which could be approaching your question are the Villarceau circles which are a 3D stereographical projection of the Hopf fibration wich takes place on torii, not cylinders:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3035513/305862

Comment: You should never refer to a 3d object as a "circle", do you mean a 3d sphere? Or torus (product of three circles)? Or product of circle and the 2d sphere? Whatever it is, it will be some compact 3d manifold $Y$. Then you can take your 6d manifold to be the product of ${\mathbb R}^3$ and $Y$. But maybe you want more than topology, it's hard to tell from what's written.

Comment: It may be useful to read about [Calabi-Yau manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold), specifically, the section [Applications in superstring theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold#Applications_in_superstring_theory), to help you fix the language to formulate your question.

Comment: Given the edit, you could take the product of the 3-dimensional torus $T^3$ and ${\mathbb R}^3$. However, most likely, you want much more structure than this, which you are not spelling out. In particular, to talk about "size" you want to have not just topology but a metric. I suspect, you want the 6d manifold to have a pseudo-Riemannian metric which is positive-definite on the tori $T^3\times \{p\}$. However, you are not even telling us what signature of this metric should be. There are many sources from which a physicist these days can learn topology and differential geometry. Start reading.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks Moishe. I already guessed that something like S1xS1xS1 (Cartesian product) tori are involved. All I want is indeed a pseudo Euclidean metric, or better, fo the large bulk structure a real Riemannian metric. I want to give time a place also, so 4D bulk. I want to let the tiny tori run around like the circles on the cylinder. Instead of point particles.

Comment: I have no idea what your terminology even means ("large bulk structure"). It is definitely not something used in math literature. You might be better off asking at physics stack exchange.