# Can a Torus be a submanifold of a Sphere?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, spheres, product-space

If I describe a $2$-torus in $4D$, as the product of two independent circles $S^1\times S^1$.
Can the resulting torus live on the $4D$-embedded sphere $S^3$?

I want to confirm points of my torus can all be placed at a constant distance from the origin.

Comment: The sphere $S^3$ is $3$-dimensional, not $4$-dimensional.

Comment: I meant the $4-$dimensional embedded $S^3$.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3035513/305862).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can. There is a well-known embedding of $S^1 \times S^1$ in $\mathbb R^3$. See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus). But $\mathbb R^3$ embeds into $S^3$. A standard embedding is given by the inverse of the stereographic projection form the north pole.

Comment: I am not sure I follow, I am wondering if I can describe a Torus as a submanifold of a Sphere. The end goal is that my Torus would be an invariant of the linear action of $SO(4)$.

Comment: @hamzakeurti The above embedding of the torus into $S^3$ produces a smooth submanifold. But invariance under the action of $SO(4)$ is a new question.

Comment: @hamzakeurti There is no nontrivial smooth action of $SO(4)$ on the 2-dimensional torus. Actually, I think the same for higher-dimensional tori.

Comment: @KritikerderElche I just thought about it, what I am trying to get to is that there exists a subgroup of $SO(4)$ which preserves the $2$-Torus through linear action. Which is why I asked this question. Since that would be a necessary condition.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Would that action be faithful?

Comment: @hamzakeurti The trivial subgroup does the job, but certainly that it is not what you are interested in ...

Comment: Right, a non-trivial linear action. A trivial action would not require the Torus to be "isodistant" from the origin.

Comment: @hamzakeurti: Trivial action of $SO(4)$, of course will not be faithful. I suggest, you accept the current answer and ask a new question, the one you are actually interested in.