# Is it possible to translate points on a $3D$ sphere to a $4D$ hypersphere

Tags: geometry, dimension-theory-analysis

Would it be possible to translate coordinates on a $3D$ sphere, say a set of coordinates on earth, to a point on a hypersphere?

I'm not sure on the possibilities of this but I cannot see why it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Consider a set of points on a 2D circle. If each coordinate pair is $(x_i,y_i)$ then consider the set of points $(x_i,y_i,0)$ - these will lie on a sphere. If you're happy with that, you can do the same from 3D to 4D.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @tomi ah I see so I am currently trying to undertake a maths ia for my ib hl course and I was going to do finding the distance between points on a sphere versus a hypersphere, but would there be no distance difference then because all that's added is a 0 for the w point and therefore it wouldn't change the distance

Comment: Sorry, but you should think that saying in your last comment "a maths ia for my ib hl" is not understandable outside your country. Could you explicitate ?

Comment: @JeanMarie since the ib is an international course taught in 146 countries I assumed people may have some knowledge of what it is. It’s essentially an essay that has to be written to explore some area of maths

Comment: I must be in the 147th country. 'ib" = "international board" ? Anyway, thanks for this partial answering but the pedestrian  I am still doesn't know what letters "i" and "b" stand for, and also what is the meaning of "ai" (artificial intelligence ??) and hl (high level ?)

Comment: @JeanMarie ib stands for international baccalaureate and it is essentially a high school diploma qualification for people finishing school. An ai stands for applications and interpretations and it is essentially the highest level (hl) of maths you can take through the ib, I hope that clears it up

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed comments. Dealing with your question there is a nice interpretation of the hypersphere of $\mathbb{R^4}$ called Hopf fibration using the so-called stereographic projection: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3035513/305862) for example.